# compare columns with list of string values in two different df and return ID which has the highest match between the lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe 'jobs' like this:

```
    jobs=
id    position  keywords
5663123 A   ["Engineer","Quality"]
5662986 B   ['Java']
5663237 C   ['Art', 'Paint', 'Director']
5663066 D   ["Junior","Motion","Designer"]
5663039 E   ['Junior', 'Designer']
5663153 F   ["Client","Specialist"]
5663266 G   ['Pyhton']
```

And I have another dataframe named 'people' as:

```
people=

pid           skills
5662321 ["Engineer","L2"]
5663383 ["Quality","Engineer","L2"]
5662556 ["Art","Director"]
5662850 ["Junior","Motion","Designer"]
5662824 ['Designer', 'Craft', 'Junior']
5652496 ["Client","Support","Specialist"]
5662949 ["Community","Manager"]
```

I want to do is match the list values of people['skills'] with jobs['keywords']

If the match is more than 2 tokens, i.e. len(list(set(A)-set(B))) >=2 then return the ID of that particular job from jobs's table jobs['id'] in a new column in people['match'] in a list because there could be more than one matches, None otherwise.

The final people df should look like:

```
people=
pid           skills                         match
5662321 ["Engineer","L2"]                    None
5663383 ["Quality","Engineer","L2"]         [5663123]
5662556 ["Art","Director"]                  [5663237]
5662850 ["Junior","Motion","Designer"]  [5663066,5663039]
5662824 ['Designer', 'Craft', 'Junior'] [5663066,5663039]
5652496 ["Client","Support","Specialist"]   [5663153]
5662949 ["Community","Manager"]              None
```

I currently have a solution in place which is not efficient at all.
Rightnow I iterate over spark dataframes row-wise which is taking a lot time for a large df.

I am open to pandas solutions as well.

Comment: You probably want to add some extra steps here, starting with denormalization by making one record per (skill, pid) pair and one per (skill, id) pair.  Then joining the tables on skill and doing some groupby.  Glancing at your sample data, I'm a bit concerned by the inconsistent use of single- and double-quotes.  Hopefully that's just due to cut&paste issues, but if "Skills" values are being stored as a JSON string rather than an array, you'll probably want to add a step to convert it from a string to a list before anything else.

Comment: Most of the functions you need should be described here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/frame.html Try to think and operate in terms of tables and columns rather than in terms of individual records

Comment: That's just my typing inconsistency, they are array of strings only. Thank you for that, I'll explore. @SarahMesser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
people.join(jobs, F.expr("size(array_intersect(skills, keywords))>=2"), "left")\
.groupBy("pid")\
.agg(F.first("skills").alias("skills"), F.collect_list("id").alias("match"))\
.withColumn("match", F.when(F.size("match")==0, None).otherwise(F.col("match")))\
.show(truncate=False)
```

The withColumn on line 4 is to just change empty lists to None as stated in the requirement.

Let me know if you face any issue.

Input:

Jobs DF:

```
+-------+--------+--------------------------+
|id     |position|keywords                  |
+-------+--------+--------------------------+
|5663123|A       |[Engineer, Quality]       |
|5662986|B       |[Java]                    |
|5663237|C       |[Art, Paint, Director]    |
|5663066|D       |[Junior, Motion, Designer]|
|5663039|E       |[Junior, Designer]        |
+-------+--------+--------------------------+
```

People DF:

```
+-------+--------------------------+
|pid    |skills                    |
+-------+--------------------------+
|5662321|[Engineer, L2]            |
|5663383|[Quality, Engineer, L2]   |
|5662556|[Art, Director]           |
|5662850|[Junior, Motion, Designer]|
+-------+--------------------------+
```

Output:

```
+-------+--------------------------+------------------+
|pid    |skills                    |match             |
+-------+--------------------------+------------------+
|5662321|[Engineer, L2]            |null              |
|5663383|[Quality, Engineer, L2]   |[5663123]         |
|5662556|[Art, Director]           |[5663237]         |
|5662850|[Junior, Motion, Designer]|[5663066, 5663039]|
+-------+--------------------------+------------------+
```